# Form Submit React and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-native

I am super new to React. Basically I have two components for now. My SearchInput-Component is a Select for cities, which does a real time search. It works super good and looks like this:

[image]

I added this component to my CityForm Component, which is a Search Form which I need to submit. And here I am stuck. For now I have just checked if submit works with a simple alert.

```
class CityForm extends React.Component {

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Try tomorrow')
  }
 
  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <SearchInput placeholder="search city" style={{ width: 200 }} />
      </form>

    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(
    <CityForm />,   
    document.getElementById('react-form')
);
```

I was thinking that submit should be kind of a post request. For now my URL won't change when I submit and I kind of need to do the post request to some kind of URL. The url for post would be smth. like

```
filter?[city_id_eq]=02000000&commit=Search
```

Am I thinking right? But also, I will need to get the city_id from the Select, which will basically always have a value before submit. Should set the value of the state of handleSubmit to the value of the select and how do I do this?

Maybe it's relevant, that's what I render in SearchInput

```
render() {
    const options = this.state.data.map(d => <Option key={d.value}>{d.text}</Option>);
    return (
      <Select
        showSearch
        value={this.state.value}
        placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        style={this.props.style}
        defaultActiveFirstOption={false}
        showArrow={false}
        filterOption={false}
        onSearch={this.handleSearch}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        notFoundContent={null}
      >
        {options}
      </Select>
    );
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve? If you want to do a GET request then fetchAPI or axios can be used. If your question is how to get the data from `SearchInput` in `CityForm` then I suggest you read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Answer (score 0):

First You create a new `value` state in Your `CityForm` component and remove the `value` state from `SearchInput` component. In other words, lift the state up. Afterwards, You can update `CityForm` new `value` state in `SearchInput` via callback function. Something in the lines of:
https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/reactjs/callback-props
Then You will have the city id available in `CityForm` component's state.

Second, use use, e.g., Axios to make the form post request.
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/react-axios-react#step-3-%E2%80%94-making-a-post-request

P.S. Look into React hooks once You get a little more comfortable with React components. ;)